# Send an event to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, modal-dialog

## Problem

Is there a way to send 'event' to another function with jQuery?
I have this code to prevent remove of row of my table to execute certain treatments, then remove the row.
I want to add a modal window between. But I do not know how to proceed.

Actually, I do like this

```
$('#delete-row').on('click', '.tr-special .remove-line-exceptionnel', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $row = $(event.target).closest('.tr-special');
    console.log($row);
    var elementSortable = $row.find('ul').attr('id');
    items = $row.find('li');
    $( items ).each(function( index ) {
      //function out of purpose     
    });
    $row.remove();
});
```

Output of console.log is

```
r.fn.init [tr.tr-special, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

I want to call my modal, after click on Delete button with class .remove-line, so in normal times I do like this

```
$('.remove-line').on('click', function (event) {
    $('#custom-width-modal').modal('show');

});
```

And what I would like is : when I press the button Confirm in my modal, the code of $('#delete-row').on('click', '.tr-special .remove-line', function (event) {.. execute.

```
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.validDelete', function(e) {
    var $row = $(e.target).closest('.tr-special');
    console.log($row);

});
```

Output of console.log is

```
r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

I hope you understand me

Comment: I don't think you understand events properly. You don't 'send' an event around, you subscribe to them. Add an event listener for click on your modal confirm button, a new one for your new action.

Comment: @StevenStark I'm not sure I understand what the OP is exactly looking for, but you can "pass" an event object that is received by it's callback to another function if desired.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Sure, but that's not their intended use what so ever. You would find yourself in a situation where one event has a target for something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply declare the `$row` variable globally...

In the `.remove-line-exceptionnel` click handler, store the element to possibly delete. Then in the `.validDelete` click handler, you remove the element.

So there is no *send an event* anywhere. There is two events... One to know which element to delete and one to actually do it.

```js
// Declare a variable globally
var $row;

// Button (or whatever) in the row
$('#delete-row').on('click', '.tr-special .remove-line-exceptionnel', function (event) {
  // Store the row element to delete
  $row = $(event.target).closest('.tr-special');
  // Show modal
  $('#custom-width-modal').modal('show');
});

// Modal button
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.validDelete', function(e) {
  // Remove the row
  $row.remove();
  // Hide modal
  $('#custom-width-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
table{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td{
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="delete-row">
  <tr class="tr-special">
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="remove-line-exceptionnel">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-special">
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="remove-line-exceptionnel">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-special">
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="remove-line-exceptionnel">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="custom-width-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary validDelete">Yes, I'm sure.</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```